# @PostMapping saving empty objects spring boot+jpa+gradle+mysql db

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I'm trying to make a crud app using **SpringBoot + JPA + HIBERNATE + GRADLE + MYSQL**. My issue is that when I hit an `@PostMapping` endpoint to save a user,  an empty object get's saved in database. Only `id` is generated but the other column shows `null`. Also when I hit `@GetMapping` it returns empty object list . I'm using **PostMan** for requests.

**Images of Postamn Requests**

**create**

[image]

**all**

[image]

**Mysql Database**

[image]

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'db.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '19'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/auto?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

**mainApplication.java**

```
package db.example.autodbconnect;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AutodbconnectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AutodbconnectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**UserEntity**

```
package db.example.autodbconnect.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;
    
}
```

**User JPA Repository**

```
 package db.example.autodbconnect.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import db.example.autodbconnect.entities.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
    
}
```

**User Service**

```
package db.example.autodbconnect.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import db.example.autodbconnect.entities.User;
import db.example.autodbconnect.repositories.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;


    public User create(User body) {
        return userRepo.save(body);

    }

    public List<User> findAll(){
        List<User> res=userRepo.findAll();
        return res;
    }
    
}
```

**User Controller**

```
package db.example.autodbconnect.contoller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import db.example.autodbconnect.entities.User;
import db.example.autodbconnect.service.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<User> create(@RequestBody User body) {
        return  new ResponseEntity<User>(userService.create(body), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> findALL(){
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(userService.findAll(),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: How the user object looks like and how your request?

Comment: Is `User` class same as `Sample`?

Comment: `public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Sample,Long> {` should be `public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {`

Comment: But you should not use the entity classes at controller level. It is bad architecture

Comment: Yes they are. They will use by jackson to set the values while deserializing

Comment: Ok  `setter` and ` getter` solved the issue. Both  `Mappings` are working. Thanks for your help and time. Are `constructor` and  `tostring()` also compulsory?

Comment: You are welcome. But as I methioned, you shouldn't use the entity class in your API

Comment: It's y first project I don't know much about the things. So can you tell me what should I do then?

Comment: Read a bout 3tier architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added getter setter methods for each field that's why it is storing null values
solution-
1-either add getter setter method for each field or
2-you can also add lombook dependency and use @Data annotation it will add getter setter method for you

Hope it will help you

Comment: Greate Answer. I tried  `@Data` from lombok but It didn't worked because I might not be doing it correctly. But I didn't know that `@Data` and `lombok` is that much important. I'm definitely  going to try it.

Comment: I recommend that you update your answer and put some code example from my code. It will be very helpful for others as most of the people don't take much interest in theoretical part and just ignores it...

Comment: In your answer it is not clear which `each fields` you are talking about. Please update your answer by specifying things and also put code as well.